# How to add same control to every screen?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Making first windows store app and need to have some controls show up at the top and bottom of every screen.  When I did some WPF dev, I created a usercontrol and added it to every page.  How is this done in windows store apps?

More specifically the header has a company logo and a status icon that changes based on an external resource (idle -> running, etc).  The footer is where navigation happens in a somewhat linear fashion.  Also, the footer displays the date and current time that continues to update. with the content in the middle changing based on what is selected in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this. It really matters on whether you need it to be the *same* control (same instance) or if it is just a header/footer control which is added to each page and changes based on what you put into it.

Firstly, if this is something that can be incorporated into a `CommandBar`, that's the first thing I suggest you try. Then you can just create a `StaticResource` for each `CommandBar`, styled in the way you want for the header and footer. When you declare each page, in the root declaration, just set:

```
Page.TopAppBar="{StaticResource MyHeader}"
Page.BottomAppBar="{StaticResource MyFooter}"
```

You can make them `Sticky` and style them in any way that you would prefer, including having a collapsed version with just an ellipsis (`...`) to hide/show it. You can store all of the data for them inside of their own ViewModels, and have the control's DataContext just bind directly to the VM so that each instantiation pulls from the same data.

If it's not something that can be incorporated into a type of `CommandBar`, then I suggest you create your own `Page` subclass. The `Template` for it will wrap its `ContentPresenter` in your custom `Header` and `Footer` objects, likely in a `Grid` panel. This way will create a new copy of them each time, so they'll still need to bind to a ViewModel.

The final option that I see is to create a parent `Page` which has, similar to the subclass method, your header and footer wrapping the content. This time though, have them wrap a `Frame`. Then, all you have to do is call `Frame.Navigate` on that `Frame`and the header/footer controls will not be recreated, only the content in between them.

You can see something similar to this done in most of the Windows 8/8.1 app samples. They create a Content Frame, then navigate that through each page of the sample, generally on a selection from a navigation `ListBox`.

If you add a bit more information, I can try and tailor the answer a bit and provide some more specificity, but these are the general ways that I can see for you to accomplish what you have described.

*Update:*

Based on what you've said, to me it seems like the easiest thing to do would be to go with the third option, a `Page` wrapping a `Frame`. I suggest this because then it makes it quite easy for the bottom bar to affect navigation, and it sounds like you don't want the header or footer to be affected by page transitions.

If you check out the official [`ListView` sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd/sourcecode?fileId=44767&pathId=1503355791), you'll note their main page is declared something like this:

```
<Page
     ...> 
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"> 
        <!-- Navigation and other stuff -->
        <Frame Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ScenarioFrame" Margin="30,50,30,0" /> 
    </Grid> 
</Page>
```

This is your basic main page declaration. You can then declare three `Rows`, one for your header, one for your Content, and one for your footer. If you want the footer to pop in and out, you can totally build the footer you have described into a `CommandBar` and include it on this page. Whenever you need to Navigate, just call `ScenarioFrame.Navigate` from your code-behind. You can now create `Page`s like normal, and `Navigate` to them like you would any other app.

This should also be 'Universal', so you should be able to include it in a `Universal` app, so long as you make sure your footer scales to the size of the screen (which you should already do). If you do try this, make sure that your navigation code in your main page is as generic as possible and the majority of the 'specialty navigation', such as Panes and settings are handled each platform-specific page, or at least via messaging (such as that provided by MvvmLight) and a `NavigationHelper` class.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Updated it to reflect the extra info